# Regular expression + No Empty String

Tags: regex, whitespace

I am using following regular expression to accept the time in 24hr format in Objective-C.

```
(^([1]?[1-9]|2[1-3])?(\\.([0-9]{1,1})?)?$)
```

It is working perfectly, but it accepts the empty string. I **don't want it to accept the empty string.** Could you please guide?

Comment: Please show an example of where it fails and your expected output

Comment: Why don't you just trim the string before checking it?

Comment: `[0-9]{1,1}` is essentially the same as `[0-9]`

Comment: @X.Jacobs:It failure of this Reg expression is that it accepts the WhietSpace character any where.

Comment: @SamyagShah.. It's better to post the code where you are using it, rather than describing it theretically. Currently your regex will match `empty string`, but not a whitespace.

Comment: If I trim it will work. But can't we modify the regular expression in such a way that it will not accept the WhiteSpace Character.

Comment: I am using it to validate the value entered by the user in UITextField class of the Cocoa iOS Library.

Comment: Sorry guys. Actually u all are right. That Regular expression will match empty string, but not a whitespace. It was accepting white space due to some logical problem in the code & not in Regular Expression. Thanks.

Comment: Is there any way that this regular expression should not accept the empty string? Please.

Comment: Just remove the optional quantifier from both the groups - `?`. It matches `0 or 1` occurrence. You just need to match `1` occurrence. So, remove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex seems to be wrong because the part dealing with minutes (the second group) contains just one digit. I thing the following pattern fits better your needs

```
^(([01]?\d)|(2[0-3]))\.([0-5]\d)$
```

The first group deals with hours (that can be in ranges 0-19 or 20-23) and the second group deals with minutes. It doesn't accept empty strings as the groups are not optional.